# javascript - regex matching devices on user agent

Tags: javascript, mobile

I'm using the PHP class "Mobile Detect" to detect user device type (tablet/phone) however I also want to detect certain devices in javascript. Can someone help me convert the following into javascript regex (just need a true/false return)?

```
var user_agent = navigator.userAgent;

var samsung = 'Galaxy.*Tab|SAMSUNG.*Tablet|Galaxy.*Tab|Android.*GT-';
// if statement checking samsung regex against user agent

var nexus = '^.*Android.*Nexus(((?:(?!Mobile))|(?:(\s(7).+))).)*$';
// if statement checking nexus7 regex against user agent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var user_agent = navigator.userAgent;

var samsung = /Galaxy.*Tab|SAMSUNG.*Tablet|Galaxy.*Tab|Android.*GT-/i;
// if statement checking samsung regex against user agent
if (samsung.test(user_agent)) {
   // This is a samsung mobile device
}

var nexus = /^.*Android.*Nexus(((?:(?!Mobile))|(?:(\s(7).+))).)*$/i;
// if statement checking nexus7 regex against user agent
if (nexus.test(user_agent)) {
   // This is a nexus mobile device
}
```

Or did you actually want help fixing malfunctioning / incomplete regular expressions?

If you need a solid regular expression, I suggest you go play around at [txt2re.com](http://txt2re.com) it's the best regular expression generator I know of.

Comment: Perfect! I've always struggled with regex, bookmarked that site as well for future assistance :)