# Is it possible to detect samsung stock browser

Tags: javascript, canvas, android-browser, navigator

Because the canvas bug of samsung stock browser, my program will cause error.
(http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39247)

So I want to disable canvas on all Samsung stock browser.

Could I detect it by navigator object or other way?

I found the same question, but it's solution looks like not perfect
([javascript - regex matching devices on user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507996/javascript-regex-matching-devices-on-user-agent))

Wiki shows Samsung has more models.
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_III)

Comment: use feature detection, not browser sniffing. Is easier and what happens if next week's Samsung comes out supporting it?

Comment: But it supports Canvas, it just has a bug.

Comment: can likely build a support test regardless, then when bug is fixed you won't be excludung those users

Comment: @charlietfl feature detection doesn't always work, for example the samsung stock browser gives a lot of false positives

Answer (score 8):

You can simply do this

```
var isSamsungBrowser = navigator.userAgent.match(/SamsungBrowser/i)
```

Comment: You can see from [here](https://developer.samsung.com/internet/user-agent-string-format.html) that it doesn't work for all Samsung devices. Some of them have strings such as `Samsung` or the device's model starting with `SGH`...

Answer (score 6):

The following regex covers almost all Samsung **mobile** devices.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/SAMSUNG|Samsung|SGH-[I|N|T]|GT-[I|N]|SM-[A|N|P|T|Z]|SHV-E|SCH-[I|J|R|S]|SPH-L/i)) {
    console.log("it's Samsung");
    // your code for Samsung Smartphones goes here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using the userAgent is enough to detect this bug. Look for the string `534.30`. For instance:

```
  if (window.navigator && window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('534.30') > 0) {
    // Clear the canvas a different way because they are using a known-bad version of the default android browser
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Does the number '534.30' represents WebKit version?
If it is, other mobile manufacturers may have this number in userAgent, too.

Comment: Yes, and one not used by Chrome Mobile. You could check for both that number and webkit, to be safer. But you can only ever be "really mostly safe" about it.

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't solve my problem. Other Android manufacturers may be detected the same version, not only Samsung. I have tested my Canvas program on Asus and HTC stock browser, it works great! Only Samsung has this canvas problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be ok:

```
const isSamsungBrowser = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('SamsungBrowser') > - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Some samsung user agents have the word "samsung" in them.  If you find "samsung" in the user agent string it's a good indicator.  However, most samsung user agents I looked at didn't contain the word samsung.  But there is a different check, all samsung model numbers (so far) are in the format "GT-xxxxxx" so we check for the user agent having "android" in, followed by "GT-" somewhere in the UA. (or the word samsung...) This is obviously a little slack but seems to catch them ok so far....