# How to target Samsung Internet in CSS?

Tags: css, cross-browser, samsung-internet

There are ways to target different browsers in CSS with media queries or like this in a selectors body:

```
-webkit-[css property]
-khtml-[css property]
-moz-[css property]
-ms-[css property]
```

But I cannot find a way to manipulate solely the Samsung Internet browser (to fix a small design issue that doesn't occur on any other browser). What can I do?

Comment: Not sure CSS can do it, but for JS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14948720/is-it-possible-to-detect-samsung-stock-browser

Answer (score 2):

These are vendor prefixes. They are not actually targeting individual browsers.

When you prefix a property with -webkit, for example, you're targeting all browsers which use WebKit as their main rendering engine, like:

- Chrome
- Safari
- Newer versions of Opera and Edge
- Almost all iOS browsers including Firefox for iOS
- Any WebKit or Chromium-based browser, including Samsung Internet

So, there isn't a specific Samsung Internet prefix you can use.